# How to Handle Passing in String Values via `mssql` package in Node Project

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am using the `mssql` package in my Node project to handle querying for data in my SQL Server db. I am running into a challenge with this particular query:

```
const idArr = ['A123', 'B456'];

SELECT DOCNO
FROM dbo.SA30301
WHERE DOCNO
IN (${idArr})
```

The problem is that, with this syntax, the values will not be passed in as strings, even though the array contains string values. So with this implementation I get an `invalid column name` error.

I've also tried this:

```
SELECT DOCNO
FROM dbo.SA30301
WHERE DOCNO
IN ('${idArr}')
```

... and while this doesn't error out, it doesn't return any records because basically both values are passed in as one long string.

Also, FYI, the type for `DOCNO` in SQL Server is `char(17)`.

So my question is, how can I make sure these values get evaluated as individual string values?

My other option may be to use a for-loop and go one by one, but that will result in many hits to the db rather than just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a Javascript's **join** function

```
SELECT DOCNO
FROM dbo.SA30301
WHERE DOCNO
IN (${idArr.map(item => `'${item}'`).join(',')})
```

You may need to escape the quotes.

Comment: And I would recommend editing your question with an example of what you mean by "individual strings"

Comment: I've edited my answer. The quotes before and after every item will make it so that you will get "A123","B456"

Comment: Nice one! I made one small edit to your answer, because in SQL Server those need to be single quotes, not double. But other than that this works perfectly!